# checking row in 2D array for duplicates-java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

im trying to make a method that searches rows and colums in an array for duplicates but what i have written so far doesnt work and i dont know how to proceed from here :

```
private boolean isOrderValid(int[][] boardNumbers){
   for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
         int CheckedNumber = boardNumbers[i][j];
         boardNumbers[i][j]=-1;
         for (int q = 0; q < Size; q++) {
             for (int l = 0; l < Size; l++) {
                 if (CheckedNumber==boardNumbers[q][l]){
                     return true;
                 }
         boardNumbers[i][j]=CheckedNumber;
         }
      }               
  }
  }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Variable names in Java should always be camelCase, not UpperCase.

Comment: "doesnt work" is not very descriptive of the problem you are having. provide an example where it fails, along with the expected and actual results.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to detect duplicates is to use the Java `Set` type, which is designed to reject duplicates. In particular, the `Set` method `add` will return `false` if a value is being added to the set which has previously been added to the set. This way you know that you've encountered a duplicate value.

So an easy way to implement a method which checks a multi-dimensional `int` array for duplicates would be this:

```
private static boolean arrayContainsDuplicateValues(int[][] multiArray) {
    Set<Integer> dupeChecker = new HashSet<>();
    int rows = multiArray.length;
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; ++rowIndex) {
        int columns = multiArray[rowIndex].length;
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns; ++colIndex) {
            int value = multiArray[rowIndex][colIndex];
            if (!dupeChecker.add(value)) {
                // We've already added this vaule to the Set before, so this
                // value is a duplicate.
                System.out.println("Dupe: " + value);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // All of the values from the array were added to the Set without any
    // duplicates being found.
    return false;
}
```

This simply iterates through each element of the array (dynamically checking the number of elements in each dimension) and then adds each value to a `Set<Integer>` which has been created purely to detect duplicates. If the call to `dupeChecker.add(value)` returns `false` then we know that we've seen the value before and the method returns `true` to indicate that the array does contain duplicate values.

Note that this method is not the most efficient. For example, your existing code seems to assume that the size of each dimension of the array is `Size` (and, as per the comment above, variable names should not start with an uppercase letter, so this ought to be `size`). If the dimensions of your array are always a known, fixed size, then you don't need to keep the code which measures the length (the "row" and "column" counts) and you could just hardcode the known, fixed size into the loop instead. But, if efficiency is not critical, then it's usually safer to keep the dynamic checking to avoid having to modify the code if the dimensions/shape of the array changes in future. Also, if you know the dimensions of the array in advance you can give the `HashSet<>()` constructor call a suitable initial capacity, to avoid forcing Java to resize the `HashSet` to suit the actual number of elements.

Oh, and do remove the call to `System.out.println`. I've left it in just so you can see which value was detected as a duplicated, but generally you should not leave calls to `System.out.println` in production code.

Answer (score 0):

you are using four loops OMG , your programs complexity would be n4.

here we can use very simple and optimized approach .

```
    private boolean isOrderValid(int[][] boardNumbers){
           Set<Integer> tempSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
           boolean dupliacteFound = false;
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                 int CheckedNumber = boardNumbers[i][j];
                 if(!tempSet.add(CheckedNumber)){
                     dupliacteFound = true;
                     break;
                 }
              }
           }
           return dupliacteFound;
    }
```